# What do I have to pay attention to when copying strings?

Tags: c, string, copy

On which factors do I have to pay attention when copying strings in C? And what can go wrong?

I can think of I need to reserve sufficient memory before copying a string and have to make sure I have enough privileges to write to the memory (try to avoid General Protection Faults), but is there anything else I have to pay attention on when copying strings? Are there any additional potential errors?

Comment: It actually was part of my homework to copy strings without making use of functions provided by string.h, yes. Since my experience with functions such as memcpy (or generally C) is very limited I wanted to make sure my custom 'strcpy' does its job fine and I did pay attention to all things that might go wrong when copying strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure that you have sufficient buffer space in the destination (i.e. know ahead how many bytes you're copying). This also means making sure that the source string is properly terminated (by a null character, i.e. `0` = `'\0'`).
- Make sure that the destination string gets properly terminated.
- If your application is character-set aware, bear in mind that some character sets can have embedded null characters, while some can have variable-length characters.

Comment: Many thanks for answering my question. Since it is all I wanted to know I am going to mark your answer as the solution in about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

C strings are conventionally arrays of non-zero bytes ended by a zero byte. Routines dealing with them get a pointer to a byte (that it, to the array starting at that byte). You should take care that the reserved place fits. Learn about `strcpy` and `strcat` and their bounded counter-parts `strncpy` and `strncat`. Also about `strdup`. And don't forget to clear the terminating byte to zero (in particular, when reaching the bound with `strncpy` etc...). Some libraries (e.g. Glib from GTK) provide nice utility functions (e.g. `g_strdup_printf`) building strings.

Read the documentation of all the functions I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. allocate sufficient memory for destination (strlen(source) + 1)
2. make sure source is not NULL
3. deal with unicode issues (string length might be less than length in
   bytes)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay attention to the definition of a string in C: they are a sequence of characters ended with a null terminating character ('\0').

All the functions in string.h will work with this assumption. Work with those functions and you should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to use any functions provided by string.h, so I have to use memcpy for now.